# How do I loop through a javascript Array in a React App that has object and get a count on a property that has a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I have this javascript array that has objects nested with in it.

```js
[{
    "MonitoringState": "disabled",
    "State_Code": 16,
    "State_Name": "running",
    "EbsOptimized": false,
    "EnaSupport": true,
    "SourceDestCheck": true,
    "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
    "SriovNetSupport": "None",
    "StateReason_Code": "None",
    "StateReason_Message": "None"
  },
  {
    "MonitoringState": "disabled",
    "State_Code": 16,
    "State_Name": "stopped",
    "EbsOptimized": false,
    "EnaSupport": true,
    "SourceDestCheck": true,
    "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
    "SriovNetSupport": "None",
    "StateReason_Code": "None",
    "StateReason_Message": "None"
  },
  {
    "MonitoringState": "disabled",
    "State_Code": 16,
    "State_Name": "running",
    "EbsOptimized": false,
    "EnaSupport": true,
    "SourceDestCheck": true,
    "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
    "SriovNetSupport": "None",
    "StateReason_Code": "None",
    "StateReason_Message": "None"
  },
  {
    "MonitoringState": "disabled",
    "State_Code": 16,
    "State_Name": "stopped",
    "EbsOptimized": false,
    "EnaSupport": true,
    "SourceDestCheck": true,
    "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
    "SriovNetSupport": "None",
    "StateReason_Code": "None",
    "StateReason_Message": "None"
  },
  {
    "MonitoringState": "disabled",
    "State_Code": 16,
    "State_Name": "running",
    "EbsOptimized": false,
    "EnaSupport": true,
    "SourceDestCheck": true,
    "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
    "SriovNetSupport": "None",
    "StateReason_Code": "None",
    "StateReason_Message": "None"
  },
  {
    "MonitoringState": "disabled",
    "State_Code": 16,
    "State_Name": "running",
    "EbsOptimized": false,
    "EnaSupport": true,
    "SourceDestCheck": true,
    "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None",
    "SriovNetSupport": "None",
    "StateReason_Code": "None",
    "StateReason_Message": "None"
  }
]
```

I want to loop through this and get the see the number of `State_Name` that are `running` and those that are `stopped`. I know I have 6 `running` and 2 `stopped`.

So I want my html to say "There are 4 running and 2 stopped". The object is actually bigger and I am doing this in a React App. I have a number of properties where I want to do the same thing. Just need a good pattern.

What is a good pattern at accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const runningCount = records.filter(r => r.State_Name === 'running').length
```

For stopped you can do:

```
const stoppedCount = records.filter(r =>r.State_Name === 'stopped').length
```

Then for your template, just do:

```
<span>There are {runningCount} running and {stoppedCount} stopped. </span>
```

The variable records is basically your array.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic use case for `reduce()`. You can loop through once counting into an object along the way.

```js
let obj = [{ "MonitoringState": "disabled", "State_Code": 16, "State_Name": "running", "EbsOptimized": false, "EnaSupport": true, "SourceDestCheck": true, "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None", "SriovNetSupport": "None", "StateReason_Code": "None", "StateReason_Message": "None"},{ "MonitoringState": "disabled", "State_Code": 16, "State_Name": "stopped", "EbsOptimized": false, "EnaSupport": true, "SourceDestCheck": true, "SpotInstanceRequestId": "None", "SriovNetSupport": "None", "StateReason_Code": "None", "StateReason_Message": "None"},{"MonitoringState": "disabled","State_Code": 16,"State_Name": "running","EbsOptimized": false,"EnaSupport": true,"SourceDestCheck": true,"SpotInstanceRequestId": "None","SriovNetSupport": "None","StateReason_Code": "None","StateReason_Message": "None" }, {"MonitoringState": "disabled","State_Code": 16,"State_Name": "stopped","EbsOptimized": false,"EnaSupport": true,"SourceDestCheck": true,"SpotInstanceRequestId": "None","SriovNetSupport": "None","StateReason_Code": "None","StateReason_Message": "None" }, {"MonitoringState": "disabled","State_Code": 16,"State_Name": "running","EbsOptimized": false,"EnaSupport": true,"SourceDestCheck": true,"SpotInstanceRequestId": "None","SriovNetSupport": "None","StateReason_Code": "None","StateReason_Message": "None" }, {"MonitoringState": "disabled","State_Code": 16,"State_Name": "running","EbsOptimized": false,"EnaSupport": true,"SourceDestCheck": true,"SpotInstanceRequestId": "None","SriovNetSupport": "None","StateReason_Code": "None","StateReason_Message": "None" }]

let counts = obj.reduce((a, item) => {
    a[item.State_Name] = (a[item.State_Name] || (a[item.State_Name] = 0)) + 1
    return a
},{})

console.log(counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work -:

```
var r = {stopped:0,running:0};
x.map((i) => {i.State_Name === 'running' ? r.running++ : r.stopped++;});
```

Comment: What if it is neither?

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good, but I wanted to contribute an answer using the new lifecycle hook in `React 16.3`. `static getDerivedStateFromProps` executes following the component's instantiation and also whenever the component receives new props. That way, you can check if any new data the component receive necessitates re-rendering the component.

You return an object to indicate a change in state or `null` to indicate new props do not require any state updates.

Please click [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) for more information from the official React documentation.

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      Num_Running: 0,
      Num_NotRunning: 0
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const results = nextProps.initialData.reduce((accum, item) => ({
      Num_Running: item.State_Name === 'running' ? ++accum.Num_Running : accum.Num_Running,
      Num_NotRunning: item.State_Name !== 'running' ? ++accum.Num_NotRunning : accum.Num_NotRunning
    }), {
      Num_Running: 0,
      Num_NotRunning: 0
    });

    if (results.Num_Running !== prevState.Num_Running || 
        results.Num_NotRunning !== prevState.Num_NotRunning)
      return { ...results };
    else
      return null;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>There are {this.state.Num_Running} running and {this.state.Num_NotRunning} stopped</div>;
  }
}

const arrayOfData = [/* your data */];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyApp initialData={arrayOfData} />,
  document.getElementById('root') // <div id="root"></div> defined in HTML
);
```

Comment: Wow this is even better!!